# Cmd+B in UIKeyComands not displaying first typed "b" afetr using the command - swift

Tags: swift, textview, uikeycommand

I'm using UIKeyCommands - Cmd+B to bold text. The code works fine to bold the text. But after i use the Cmd+B and when I type "b" the first time it doesn't display on my textView.

Here's the code:

```
override public var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
     let commands = [ UIKeyCommand(input: "B", modifierFlags: .command, action: #selector(keyTapped(command:)))]
return commands
}
 @objc private func keyTapped(command: UIKeyCommand) {
 if command.input == "B" && command.modifierFlags == .command {
       print("Bold text")
     } 
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `b` instead of `B`

Comment: @aheze tried it it also has the same behaviour.